# Is there an expression to downcast and simultaneously access a property in F#?

Tags: f#, intellisense, downcast, c#-to-f#

In C#, in order to access a property/method I might downcast to a type and then access the property:

```
Fruit f = new Banana();
((Banana)f).Peel();
```

What is the equivalent in F#? I tried the following but the intellisense after typing the period does not give any members of the `Banana` type so I'm guessing this isn't valid.

```
let f = new Banana()
(f :?> Banana).Peel()
```

I know I can do it by introducing an intermediate `let` statement but was wondering if there was a one liner.

**UPDATE**

Ok I was trying to give a general example but I guess something got lost in my translation.  I'm working with Excel interop.  In any case here is the more specific code.

`(worksheet.Cells.[rowNumber, dateColumn] :?> Excel.Range).<member here>`

But it looks like it was just a temporary glitch in intellisense because today (after rebooting my computer) it seems to work fine.  Yesterday it was just showing me basic object members of  `Equals, GetHashCode, GetType, and ToString`.  Now today this same expression is giving me all the members of the `Excel.Range` class. So I it looks like everything works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial guess is correct, this code works:

```
type Fruit() =
    member me.Test() = printfn "Test"

type Banana() =
    inherit Fruit()
    member me.Peel() = printfn "Peeling !"

let f = new Banana() :> Fruit
(f :?> Banana).Peel()
```

You are not showing how did you define those types, probably you have something wrong there.

Also keep in mind that in F# you have to be explicit to upcast. In your example your `f` object is already a `Banana`, nothing in your code upcast it to a `Fruit`.

Comment: Thanks good point, you're right my translation from C# was not correct.  Updated my question all seems to be working now.